# Serial port read is not complete

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, tty, termios

The functions below are used consequently to read data from serial port under Linux. I can read the complete data when I debug, but when I launch the program, *read_buffer* seems not to be complete. I receive the small part of the data correctly but the rest of the buffer is completely *zero*. What could be the problem?

```
int8_t __serial_port_open(uint8_t *port)
{
    mode_t perms = S_IRWXU;
    fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC, perms);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (__serial_port_configure() != 0)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}

static int8_t __serial_port_configure(void)
{
    struct termios attr;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &attr) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (cfsetispeed(&attr, B115200) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (cfsetospeed(&attr, B115200) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    attr.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    attr.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    attr.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    attr.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    attr.c_cflag |= (CS8);
    attr.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;
    attr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    attr.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    attr.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &attr) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int8_t __serial_port_read(uint8_t *read_buffer, uint32_t nbytes_to_read, uint32_t *nbytes_read)
{
    do
    {
        *nbytes_read = read(fd, read_buffer, nbytes_to_read);
        if (*nbytes_read == -1)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    } while (*nbytes_read == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the man](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read)

> read() attempts to read **up to count bytes** from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file),

In other words `count` parameter is the maximum bytes you want to read, but read can return a different number of bytes.

Returned value gives you the number of read bytes from FD.

To simply solve it you can do a loop receiving bytes until the expected length is reached, reading 1 byte a time.

Other solution can be implemented using [Read Timeouts](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/%7Estrupp/serial.html#3_1_5)